# jQuery custom scrollbar plugin doesn't update with horizontalScroll: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I’m using jquery plugin [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

source :
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

It works very well in vertical mode.
I can call mCustomScrollbar and call the update method.

See this fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/2mU7H/1/

But in horizontal mode, i have an issue when i call the update method. There is no content.

See this fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/4CW3p/1/

Do you know why ?

JS Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").mCustomScrollbar({
        horizontalScroll: true,
        scrollButtons: {
            enable: true
        },
        theme: "dark"
    });
});

$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#content").show();
    $("#content").mCustomScrollbar("update");
});

$("#button_close").click(function () {
    $("#content").hide();
});
```

CSS code

```
#content {
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #666;
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div id="content">
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<p id="button">Show Content</p>
<p id="button_close">Hide Content</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXL6u/)

**You forgot the `autoExpandHorizontalScroll` setting :)**

---

```
$("#content").mCustomScrollbar({
    horizontalScroll: true,
    scrollButtons: {
        enable: true
    },
    theme: "dark",
    advanced: {
        autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true
    }
});
```